# How to open a previous instance of an Activity and recreate it?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-stack

Basically what I need is to recreate one `Activity` each time I call `startActivity()` moving the instance to the front and not destroy the other activities.

For instance, if I have in the activity stack

> A->B->C->D

and from D I want to open B, the flag I currently use is `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` which leave the Activity stack in this state: `A->C->D->B`. That order in the activity stack is perfect, however, with that flag the `Activity` is not recreated and `onNewIntent()` is called.

Because the complexity of the `Activity` I do not want to refactor a lot of things, what I want is to recreate B from scratch (`onCreate()` has to be called) instead of execute my logic in `onNewIntent()` method. The activity stack should have the same state as if I use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`. Any idea? Your help will be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Will it always be this order or do you need it this way if, say, you have an E and it calls C?

Comment: [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) might be what you want

Comment: That was just an example, the order coulb be diferent, basically what I need is to have only one instannce of each activity and in the case we call startActivity requesting an Activity already present in the activity, it has to be moved to the front but I want onCreate method be called.

Comment: @codeMagic using that flag it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your work happens in `onCreate()` and you want the same stuff to work within `onNewIntent()`, then you could do potentially get away with a simple re-factor.  Where all your code is in the `setupActivity()` call.

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceStateF) 
{
   super.onCreate (savedInstanceStateF);
   setupActivity();
}

public void onNewIntent(Intent intentF)
{
   super.onNewIntent(intentF);
   setupActivity();
}
```